# Transpose Multiple Columns Into Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie with VBA. I have a Dataset with 1000+ companies that lists multiple contacts and different columns. Trying to write a VBA script to create rows for each individual contact. Please see below for a visual.

```
Existing Table

| CompanyName1| Company1 Data| Contact 1| Contact 2| Contact N|
| CompanyNameN| CompanyN Data| Contact 1| Contact 2| Contact N|
```

To

```
| CompanyName1| Company1 Data| Contact 1|
| CompanyName1| Company1 Data| Contact 2|
| CompanyName1| Company1 Data| Contact N|
| CompanyNameN| CompanyN Data| Contact 1|
| CompanyNameN| CompanyN Data| Contact 2|
| CompanyNameN| CompanyN Data| Contact N|
```

```
Dim cr As Long ‘current row
dim cc As Long ‘current column

For cr = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, “A”).End(xlUp).Row
   For cc = 5 to Cells(Columns.Count, “?”)
```

Know this isn’t close to being complete. Not sure where to go.

Comment: If you google "excel unpivot" or excel depivot" you'll get some good starting points.

Comment: Eg here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+unpivot

Comment: Skip VBA and use Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
Sub demo()
    Dim i, j, idx, res(), arr
    arr = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
    idx = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) ' Update start row# if table has header row(s)
        For j = 3 To UBound(arr, 2)
           ReDim Preserve res(0 To 2, idx)
           res(0, idx) = arr(i, 1)
           res(1, idx) = arr(i, 2)
           res(2, idx) = arr(i, j)
           idx = idx + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(idx - 1, 3).Value = Application.Transpose(res)
End Sub
```

You also can get it done with Power Query unpivot.